# Validar el clik cuando se ingrese a un componente en angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

Estoy tratando de validar cuando un usuario haga clic dentro de un componente en mi aplicación con `angular 8`

Trate de hacerlo en el `app-component`  pero ralentiza mi aplicación demasiado, necesito validar si hace `clic` para poder saber si tiene permisos sobre el formulario, esto se debe a que el admin puede eliminar el permiso a ese modulo para el usuario.

Este es el código que implemente , es el que ralentiza

```
fromEvent(document, 'click').subscribe(
  () => {
    if (this.tienePermiso !== null && this.tienePermiso !== undefined) {
      this.validacionUsuarios();
    } else {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
      localStorage.clear();
    }
  },
  error => {
    const errorMessage = <any>error;
    this.notif.error('Error', errorMessage, ConfiguracionNotificacion.configRightTopNoClose);
    console.log(errorMessage);
  });
```

Quisiera saber si hay una mejor forma de hacerlo o si existe una forma de hacerlo con `angular`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se si sea la mejor solucion pero esto funciono para mi.

En cada componente me toca agregar el código que valida el clic dentro del `component`, almacenarlo en una variable y suscribirme a el.

```
 const obs = fromEvent(this.el.nativeElement, 'click').pipe(
      map((e: any) => {
        this.moduleValidationService.metodo(this.variable);
      })
    );
    obs.subscribe((resulr) => console.log(resulr));
```

No hice el método global ya que al agregarlo a los `component` principales como `app-component` este método se ejecuta siempre que se haga clic dentro de la aplicación.